# Using javascript to get the clicked html link id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I get the id of clicked link and use that id of the link to update in my another field.

```
<div id="menu">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" id="home">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="Untitled-1.html" id="contact">contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="contact">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div> <!--menu-->
```

Once the link is clicked I want "`myspan`" field to be updated..

```
<div id="current-page">
    <span> you are here: </span>
    <span id="myspan">id of current page</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I recommend to read a jQuery tutorial to learn these basics operations: http://learn.jquery.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** or `this.id` to get the `id` of your clicked anchor as well as **[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** to set the text of your span based on the retrieved `id`:

```
$('#menu ul li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).prop('id'); // or this.id
    $('#myspan').text(id);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/69NAb/)**

Comment: `var id = $(this).prop('id');` can be `var id = this.id;`

Comment: Sure, I've added your suggestion.